# How do you exit minecraft on kindle fire 0.8.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So my friend has a kindle fire and she can't exit her world or create a new one so we want to know how we can exit on her world so please help us.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken the Kindle Fire has a switch bar at the bottom or side of your screen. Tap once or twice in that location and three white dots should appear. The bar should look like this:

[image]

You will be given:

The home option: This returns you to the very home of your Kindle.

The Back Option: To go back a page (this is probably the button you need.

The Options Option

And the Search option.

Click on the Back option. This should take you to the main menu of your game or app.

(Picture from BusinessInsider.com)